# Identify burned transistor on multi-tool PCB - top marking CM ... JA200

Tags: transistors, identification

I am trying to identify the transistor that fried on this circuit board of a 12 V multi-tool. I can make out CM then JA200. Greatly appreciate any help with ID. I hate throwing things away.

[image: PCB]

[image: Transistor closeup]

Comment: Not enuf clues , it could be dozens of parts  , find a good board by searching the product teardown or service manual   e.g. https://www.comchiptech.com/admin/files/product/QW-JTR44%20CMS50N10D-HF%20RevB.pdf

Comment: How about a picture of the whole board so we can get some context. What precipitated the device to fail? Was it stalled?

Comment: Are there only two leads attached to the board? (Looks like it to me.)

Comment: @jonk The tab looks to be connected to a large plane around the perimeter of the board, to me. I don't think that's a separate thing.

Comment: @Hearth hard to tell for me. Thanks.

Comment: Any similar devices next to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is going to be an N-channel MOSFET.
Your current MOSFET was obviously under specified so you'll want a better one (lower on-resistance and lower input capacitance would be good this to look for to make a motor-controller MOSFET "better"). I made those assumptions because your chip clearly has thermal failure (you didn't say you dropped it or hit it with a hammer).
Here is a good one that can handle many amps at your 12VDC supply with PWM speed control.
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRLR8256TRPBF/2271900
Unfortunately, you'll pay $1 for the part and 7-$12 for shipping.

Comment: Thank you ! Part ordered.. I was cutting pipe and in bound up. Before I could shut it off it failed. I was hoping I might be able to upgrade the part. Thanks again. My dad turns over in his grave if I don't fix things rather than throw them away.

Comment: Well I received the transistor and installed it and I get almost no current coming to the motor and the transistor is getting pretty hot. Any thoughts

Comment: @Overcashier I assume this board is to control the speed? Does the motor turn if you connect it directly to the power supply? It may be damaged and that in turn blew the previous MOSFET.

Comment: The motor is seized or a winding inside the motor crapped out.  Also, check if your power supply blew when the transistor blew. Or, if it is working, make sure it is not going into "protection mode' when connected to your motor and control board.  In protection mode, the power supply gives a small "chirp" of power to make sure there is some load before ramping up to full current.

Comment: Yes the motor works with 9 volts from a power supply. I installed the new transistor as recommended by GT Electronics and read very little current coming to the motor and the new transistor gets very hot

Comment: What Vgsth on your new MOSFET? What Vgs voltage can you measure with your multimeter before it becomes too hot?

Comment: Thanks winny. Complete rookie here. I'm not sure where to measure the voltage on the MOSFET.

Comment: If I put 12 volts to the board which is what the rechargeable battery is everything gets hot even the leads to the motor. If I set supply to 9 volts the motor will hum like it's trying. Again everything gets hot at 9 volts